Best way to mount Romex coming into panel on unfinished wall
I've added a basement subpanel on a wall that is both undiminished (panel mounted on top of studs, not between them) and offset between ceiling joints. Both of these factors making organising the incoming circuits tricky.
My question is two-fold:
1.) Are there any applicable NEC 2020 guidelines I need to follow here?
2.) Are there any best practices or creative suggestions you might have to make this more ideal?
I’ve got the 4 wire hangers for the kitchen runs coming in, staples for single wires, and zips with attached screws for doubles.
Also, I know the S for the HWT is unusual but hoping it’s not a violation. I wanted to make it easy to swap the appliance without going into the panel itself.


The only requirement I can find via NEC is that the Romex be stapled within 12” of the panel. I believe the solve here is just to add a cross section between the studs and behind the conduit. Then staple each circuit onto that. Otherwise it’s just tidying up what’s already there.

And the missing cover screws..
